# innerHTML contents not showing '+' sign - phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, innerhtml

I have below code in my phonegap code

```
var mailing_row1 = document.getElementById('mailingTable').insertRow(1);
var mailing_row1_z = mailing_row1.insertCell(0);

warranty = "4(+1)"; // This warranty is getting dynamically, 
                    // this is for an example
mailing_row1_z.innerHTML = warranty;
mailing_row1_z.align = "center";

......
some other codes
    ......

mailingHTMLContent = $("#mailingTable").html();
```

and this  `mailingHTMLContent`posting to a `url` using jquery, and iam getting the `warranty` variable as `4(1)` without '+' sign when iam getting back that html.
What is the issue, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to set innerText property

Comment: tried innerText also, same issue.

Comment: Show how you are sending the value to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is not there?

```
mailingHTMLContent = $("#mailingTable").html();
console.log(mailingHTMLContent);
//alert(mailingHTMLContent);
```

You say you are setting it to a URL, you would need to encode it if it is part of the querysting

```
mailingHTMLContent = encodeURIComponent($("#mailingTable").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your warranty to use the HTML entity:

```
warranty = "4(&#43;1)";
```